# IntelliJ Idea doesn't create manifest.mf, pom.xml, pom.properties

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, manifest.mf

I am quite new to Java, although I worked with some projects. I use IntelliJ IDEA, and I have issue with my web project.

Whenever I RUN the project from IntelliJ and when it's made and built - my localizations texts are not shown, but everything is ok if I use mvn install and deploy the war file manually.

What I found is that jars built with IntelliJ don't have MANIFEST.MF generated and couple of other files.

This is IntelliJ jar

[image]

This is jar when I run mvn install from console:
[image]

Can somebody help with this, why this happens? I have same maven used for compiling as I use for console run:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you are using to build with IntelliJ?

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Like, there should be a Maven View that you can open (I think it's on the right side of the editor). It should show the various tasks you can execute on the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Maven project, then you can choose one on the tasks on the right of the editor.

`jar` or `package` should generate a JAR file.

[image: Maven options]

Comment: yes, I have, but I don't have green Run button activated. As I understood I need to run Maven Goal first?

Comment: I don't know how your `pom.xml` is setup, but this screenshot is from an IntelliJ created Maven project. These tasks are simply a shortcut to the command line `mvn` commands for the current project location.

Comment: as I understand I need first to run maven goal with install so it resolves all the dependencies? but I don't understand why? I already did it in the same project folder  with runnin console: mvn install

Comment: The `compile` task should be enough to pull in the dependencies. What does that have to do with IntelliJ building JAR files? The `package` task should also pull in dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a software tool that helps manage a project and automate builds. By default, however you have to select Maven as the desired type of project when you go to create a new project.

Basically, [create a *Maven* project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-maven.html)! :)

Comment: It's existing big project which I cloned and opened pom.xml with IntelliJ IDEA it recognized it as Maven project, I put screenshot which shows that Maven is used for this in IntelliJ, jars are also created OK by IntelliJ, just without the files I am speaking about.

Comment: you can actually do this after the project is already created.  but this is correct.  If you don't tell Intellij it's a maven project, it's just going to compile your classes and .jar them up.  If you had external dependencies in your pom file, you'd likely also notice that they wouldn't be listed in your intellij dependencies until you set it up as a maven project.